# Проблема вычисления обратной матрицы при типе float

Tags: c++, алгоритм, матрицы, типы-данных, qr

Нужно посчитать число обусловленности матрицы по определению и дать оценку снизу для этого числа (то есть, экспериментальная оценка).

Число обусловленности по определению: condA = ||A^(-1)||*||A||. Дело в том, что ДО этого задания в программе был реализован метод Гаусса для решения СЛАУ и метод qr-разложения. Чтобы обратить матрицу (а дана матрица 4х4), то я просто решаю четыре уравнения, где правая часть сначала (1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1). Получаю обратную матрицу, умножаю на исходную и получаю единичную. Всё бы хорошо, однако подобрали нам такую матрицу, при которой именно с типом "float" при перемножении получается не единичная. С типом "double" все хорошо, а вот именно при "float" - ерунда.

---

Сама матрица (она же в считываемом файле):

```
  0.2910         1.8100         9.3110         9.1100         4.2280   
  1.4500         8.5790        44.1950        42.9950        20.4290   
 -0.2900        -1.7980        -9.2500        -9.0500        -4.2080   
  0.0000         0.0820         0.4100         0.4500         0.1220
```

---

При перемножении исходной матрицы (см.выше) и обратной получается не совсем единичная матрица (на некоторых местах всплывают числа в духе 0.06 и т.п..)
Еще раз повторюсь, такое происходит только при типе "float". За код прошу особо не ругать, знаю, что он загроможден сильно.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <float.h>
using namespace std;

typedef float tdouble;

const tdouble eps = 1e-16; //при 1e-8 DATA9 не работает
const unsigned n = 4;

void product(tdouble**, tdouble*, tdouble*);
void product(tdouble**, tdouble**, tdouble**);
void output(tdouble**, tdouble*);
void output(tdouble*);
void output(tdouble **);
void changing(tdouble**, tdouble*, int, int);
bool gausss(tdouble**, tdouble*);
void qr(tdouble**, tdouble*, tdouble**);
void qr(tdouble**, tdouble*, tdouble*, tdouble*, tdouble*, tdouble**);
void reverse(tdouble**, tdouble*, tdouble*);
void spherical(tdouble*, tdouble*)ж
tdouble octahedron(tdouble*);
tdouble octahedron(tdouble*, tdouble*);
tdouble cubic(tdouble*, tdouble*);
tdouble cubic(tdouble *);
tdouble cubic_matrix(tdouble **);
tdouble octah_matrix(tdouble **);


int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

tdouble **mtx, **mtxun, *vect, *vectun;
mtx = new tdouble *[n]; //массив указателей 
mtxun = new tdouble *[n]; //неизменяемая матрица
vect = new tdouble[n];
vectun = new tdouble[n];

ifstream filemat;


filemat.open("U:\\FS13\\FS2-x3\\Melikhov\\Metody_vych\\LLaba1 \\DATA9.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    mtxun[i] = new tdouble[n];
    mtx[i] = new tdouble[n];
    for (int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++)
    {
        filemat >> (j == 4 ? vect[i] : mtx[i][j]); //если 
        j == 4 ? vectun[i] = vect[i] : mtxun[i][j] = mtx[i][j];
    }
}
filemat.close();

cout << "\t\tВывод исходной матрицы и вектора правой части" << endl << endl;
output(mtx, vect); //вывод на экран матрицы и правого вектор


//Проверка на вырожденность
bool h = gausss(mtx, vect);

tdouble product_diagonal_elements = mtx[0][0]; //произведение диагональных элементов (для проверки вырожденности)
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    product_diagonal_elements *= mtx[i][i];

if (!h || abs(product_diagonal_elements) < eps) //если модуль произведения диагональных элементов меньше эпсилон, то вывод сообщения
{
    cout << "Матрица вырожденная. До свидания!";
}
else //иначе 
{
    tdouble *sol = new tdouble[n], *check = new tdouble[n]; 
    tdouble *sin1 = new tdouble[n], *sin2 = new tdouble[n], *sin3 = new tdouble[n], *sin4 = new tdouble[n]; //единичная правая часть 
    tdouble *solr1 = new tdouble[n], *solr2 = new tdouble[n], *solr3 = new tdouble[n], *solr4 = new tdouble[n]; //решение с единичной правой частью
    tdouble *solv1 = new tdouble[n], *solv2 = new tdouble[n], *solv3 = new tdouble[n], *solv4 = new tdouble[n]; //решение с единичной правой частью
    tdouble **mtxrev = new tdouble*[n]; //обратная матрица
    tdouble nun_cub, nrev_cub, condex_cub; //норма исходной, норма обратной, число обусловленности
    tdouble nun_oct, nrev_oct, condex_oct;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        (i == 0 ? sin1[i] = 1 : sin1[i] = 0);
        (i == 1 ? sin2[i] = 1 : sin2[i] = 0);
        (i == 2 ? sin3[i] = 1 : sin3[i] = 0);
        (i == 3 ? sin4[i] = 1 : sin4[i] = 0);
    }


    //приводим к первоначальному виду mtx и vect
    tdouble **T = new tdouble*[n], **mtxcheck = new tdouble*[n]; //создаем новый массив T - единичную матрицу. Понадобится для получения матрицы Q
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        T[i] = new tdouble[n];
        mtxrev[i] = new tdouble[n];
        mtxcheck[i] = new tdouble[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            T[i][j] = (i == j ? 1 : 0); //если i=j, тогда присваем 1, иначе - 0
            mtx[i][j] = mtxun[i][j]; //в mtx записываем неизмененную матрицу mtxun для восстановления первой
        }
        vect[i] = vectun[i]; //аналогично с вектором
    }

    //QR-метод
    qr(mtx, vect, sin1, sin2, sin3, sin4, T);

    ////Транспонируем T в Q, создаем массив A
    tdouble **Q = new tdouble*[n], **A = new tdouble*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Q[i] = new tdouble[n];
        A[i] = new tdouble[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            Q[i][j] = T[j][i];
    }

    //Находим обратную матрицу
    reverse(mtx, sin1, solr1);
    reverse(mtx, sin2, solr2);
    reverse(mtx, sin3, solr3);
    reverse(mtx, sin4, solr4);

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (j == 0)
                mtxrev[i][j] = solr1[i];
            else 
                if (j == 1) 
                    mtxrev[i][j] = solr2[i];
                else
                    if (j == 2)
                        mtxrev[i][j] = solr3[i];
                    else
                        if (j == 3)
                            mtxrev[i][j] = solr4[i];
        }
    }

    cout << "Обратная матрица" << endl;
    output(mtxrev);
    product(mtxun, mtxrev, mtxcheck);
    cout << "Проверка" << endl;
    output(mtxcheck);


    cout << endl << endl << "Кубическая норма" << endl;
    nun_cub = cubic_matrix(mtxun);
    nrev_cub = cubic_matrix(mtxrev);
    condex_cub = nun_cub * nrev_cub;
    cout << endl << "Норма исходной матрицы = " << nun_cub << endl << "Норма обратной матрицы = " << nrev_cub << endl << "Произведение норм = " << condex_cub << endl;
    cout << endl << endl << "Октаэдрическая норма" << endl;
    nun_oct = octah_matrix(mtxun);
    nrev_oct = octah_matrix(mtxrev);
    condex_oct = nun_oct * nrev_oct;
    cout << endl << "Норма исходной матрицы = " << nun_oct << endl << "Норма обратной матрицы = " << nrev_oct << endl << "Произведение норм = " << condex_oct << endl;

    //Обратный ход
    reverse(mtx, vect, sol);

    tdouble n_dx, n_db, //нормы разностей dx, db
            nx_d, nb_d, //нормы деления х, b
            n_x, n_b; //нормы x и b
    tdouble max_div, norm_div; //максимум деления, норма деления

    tdouble o_dx, o_db, ox_d, ob_d, o_x, o_b, maxo_div, normo_div; //октаэдрическая

    n_x = cubic(sol); 
    o_x = octahedron(sol);
    //cout << endl << "n_x " << n_x << endl;
    n_b = cubic(vectun);
    o_b = octahedron(vectun);
    //cout << endl << "n_b " << n_b << endl;
    max_div = 0;
    maxo_div = 0;

    //Приводим к исходному виду vect и mtx
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            mtx[i][j] = mtxun[i][j];
        vect[i] = vectun[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        vect[i] += 0.01; //возмущаем i-ую компоненту вектора vect
        //cout << "VECT" << endl;
        //output(vect);
        n_db = cubic(vect, vectun);
        o_db = octahedron(vect, vectun);
        //cout << endl << "n_db " << n_db << endl;
        qr(mtx, vect, T);
        reverse(mtx, vect, solv1);
        //cout << endl;  output(solv1); cout << endl;
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                mtx[k][j] = mtxun[k][j];
            vect[k] = vectun[k];
        }
        n_dx = cubic(solv1, sol); 
        o_dx = octahedron(solv1, sol);
        //cout << endl << "n_dx " << n_dx << endl;
        nx_d = n_dx / n_x;
        ox_d = o_dx / o_x;
        //cout << endl << "nx_d " << nx_d << endl;
        nb_d = n_db / n_b;
        ob_d = o_db / o_b;
        //cout << endl << "nb_d " << nb_d << endl;
        norm_div = nx_d / nb_d;
        normo_div = ox_d / ob_d;
        //cout << endl << "norm_div " << norm_div << endl;
        if (max_div < norm_div) max_div = norm_div;
        if (maxo_div < norm_div) maxo_div = normo_div;
    }

    cout << endl << "Оценка снизу (кубическая норма): " << max_div << endl;
    cout << endl << "Оценка снизу (октаэдрическая норма): " << maxo_div << endl;
    delete[] sin1;
    delete[] sin2;
    delete[] sin3;
    delete[] sin4;
    delete[] check;
    delete[] sol;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        delete[] A[i];
        delete[] Q[i];
        delete[] T[i];
    }
    delete[] A;
    delete[] Q;
    delete[] T;
}

cin.get();

delete[] vect;
delete[] vectun;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    delete[] mtx[i];
    delete[] mtxun[i];
}
delete[] mtx;
delete[] mtxun;
}

void reverse(tdouble **mtx, tdouble *vect, tdouble *sol)
{
//Обратный ход/
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    tdouble temp = 0;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) //цикл с первого раза не пройдет, поэтому пустой массив sol[j] себя не обнаружит сначала, а обнаружит только после первой итерации внешнего цикла
        temp += mtx[i][j] * sol[j];
    sol[i] = (vect[i] - temp) / mtx[i][i];
}
}

bool gausss(tdouble **mtx, tdouble *vect)
{
tdouble c; //коэффициент масштабирования
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) //двигаемся по столбцам 
{
    tdouble temp = abs(mtx[j][j]); //ищем максимум в столбце, запоминая j,j-й элемент (ищем всегда на диагонали и ниже)
    int mem = j; //переменная для запоминания номера строки, где ищется максимум
    for (int i = j + 1; i < n; i++) //от j+1, потому что под диагональю ищем максимальный элемент
        if (temp < abs(mtx[i][j])) 
        {
            temp = abs(mtx[i][j]);  //запоминаем новый максимум 
            mem = i;  //запоминаем соответствующую строку
        }
    if (temp < eps) return false; //если максимум сравним с нулем, то возвращаем false, то есть дальше работа программы бессмысленна

    changing(mtx, vect, mem, j); //меняем местами строки

    for (int i = j + 1; i < n; i++) //цикл для вычисления коэффициентов масштабирования и преобразования 
    {
        c = mtx[i][j] / mtx[j][j]; 
        for (int k = j; k < n; k++)
            mtx[i][k] -= c * mtx[j][k]; //пересчитываем i-ю строку в матрице (линейная комбинация)...
        vect[i] -= c * vect[j]; //... и в векторе
    }
}
return true; //возвращаем истину
}

void qr(tdouble **mtx, tdouble *vect, tdouble **T) //принцип: меняем местами строки так, чтобы не было деления на ноль. Затем вычисляем коэффициенты и заменяем строки на линейные комбинации
{
//QR-метод
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) //идем по строке
{
    //int z = k; //запоминаем номер строки
    //while (abs(mtx[z][k]) < eps && z < n) //пока нулевой элемент, увеличиваем z, запоминающую строку. Также проверяется выход за пределы массива. 
    //  z++; 
    //if (z != k) 
    //  changing(mtx, vect, z, k);
    tdouble c, s, temp_sqr; //c,s - коэффициенты, temp_sqr - временный корень 
    for (int i = k + 1; i < n; i++) //сдвигаемся на строчку вниз и считаем: 
    {   //подсчет коэффициентов
        if (abs(mtx[i][k]) < eps) continue;
        temp_sqr = sqrt(mtx[k][k] * mtx[k][k] + mtx[i][k] * mtx[i][k]);
        c = mtx[k][k] / temp_sqr;
        s = mtx[i][k] / temp_sqr;
        tdouble temp, tempT;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)//k
        { //замена на линейные комбинации
            tempT = T[k][j];
            T[k][j] = c * T[k][j] + s * T[i][j];
            T[i][j] = -s * tempT + c * T[i][j];
            if (j >= k) // чтобы лишний раз не пересчитывать нули
            {
                temp = mtx[k][j]; //сохраняем первую строку во временную переменную
                mtx[k][j] = c * mtx[k][j] + s * mtx[i][j]; //заменяем k-ю строку на лк с коэффициентами c и s
                mtx[i][j] = -s * temp + c * mtx[i][j]; //заменяем j-ю строку на лк с использованием первоначальной k-й строки
            }
        } //аналогично с вектором правой части
        temp = vect[k];
        vect[k] = c * vect[k] + s * vect[i];
        vect[i] = -s * temp + c * vect[i];
    }
}
}
void qr(tdouble **mtx, tdouble *vect, tdouble *sin1, tdouble *sin2, tdouble *sin3, tdouble *sin4, tdouble **T) //принцип: меняем местами строки так, чтобы не было деления на ноль. Затем вычисляем коэффициенты и заменяем строки на линейные комбинации
{
//QR-метод
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) //идем по строке
{
    //int z = k; //запоминаем номер строки
    //while (abs(mtx[z][k]) < eps && z < n) //пока нулевой элемент, увеличиваем z, запоминающую строку. Также проверяется выход за пределы массива. 
    //  z++; 
    //if (z != k) 
    //  changing(mtx, vect, z, k);
    tdouble c, s, temp_sqr; //c,s - коэффициенты, temp_sqr - временный корень 
    for (int i = k + 1; i < n; i++) //сдвигаемся на строчку вниз и считаем: 
    {   //подсчет коэффициентов
        if (abs(mtx[i][k]) < eps) continue;
        temp_sqr = sqrt(mtx[k][k] * mtx[k][k] + mtx[i][k] * mtx[i][k]);
        c = mtx[k][k] / temp_sqr;
        s = mtx[i][k] / temp_sqr;
        tdouble temp, tempT;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)//k
        { //замена на линейные комбинации
            tempT = T[k][j];
            T[k][j] = c * T[k][j] + s * T[i][j];
            T[i][j] = -s * tempT + c * T[i][j];
            if (j >= k) // чтобы лишний раз не пересчитывать нули
            {
                temp = mtx[k][j]; //сохраняем первую строку во временную переменную
                mtx[k][j] = c * mtx[k][j] + s * mtx[i][j]; //заменяем k-ю строку на лк с коэффициентами c и s
                mtx[i][j] = -s * temp + c * mtx[i][j]; //заменяем j-ю строку на лк с использованием первоначальной k-й строки
            }
        } //аналогично с вектором правой части
        temp = vect[k];
        vect[k] = c * vect[k] + s * vect[i];
        vect[i] = -s * temp + c * vect[i];
        temp = sin1[k];
        sin1[k] = c * sin1[k] + s * sin1[i];
        sin1[i] = -s * temp + c * sin1[i];
        temp = sin2[k];
        sin2[k] = c * sin2[k] + s * sin2[i];
        sin2[i] = -s * temp + c * sin2[i];
        temp = sin3[k];
        sin3[k] = c * sin3[k] + s * sin3[i];
        sin3[i] = -s * temp + c * sin3[i];
        temp = sin4[k];
        sin4[k] = c * sin4[k] + s * sin4[i];
        sin4[i] = -s * temp + c * sin4[i];
    }
}
}

void product(tdouble **mtx, tdouble *sol, tdouble *check)
{
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //фиксировали строку
{
    check[i] = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) //двигаемся по столбцам и....
        check[i] += mtx[i][j] * sol[j]; //перемножаем
}
}

void product(tdouble **mtxun, tdouble **mtxrev, tdouble **mtxcheck)
{
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        mtxcheck[i][j] = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < n; m++)
        {
            mtxcheck[i][j] += mtxun[i][m] * mtxrev[m][j];
        }
    }
}
}

void output(tdouble *sol)
{
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    cout << fixed << setprecision(4) << setw(42) << sol[i] << endl;
}

void output(tdouble **mtx, tdouble *vect)
{
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //фиксировали строку
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) //поехали по столбцам
        cout << fixed << setprecision(4) << setw(14) << (j == n ? vect[i] : mtx[i][j]); //если j==n, то вывести вектор (последний столбец), иначе - матрицу
    cout << endl;
}
}

void output(tdouble **mtx)
{
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //фиксировали строку
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) //поехали по столбцам
        cout << fixed << setprecision(4) << setw(14) << mtx[i][j]; //если j==n, то вывести вектор (последний столбец), иначе - матрицу
    cout << endl;
}
}

void changing(tdouble **mtx, tdouble *vect, int line1, int line2)
{
tdouble *t = mtx[line2]; //запоминаем адрес
mtx[line2] = mtx[line1];
mtx[line1] = t;
tdouble r = vect[line2];
vect[line2] = vect[line1];
vect[line1] = r;
}

void spherical(tdouble *vectun, tdouble *check)
{
tdouble diff, diff2 = diff = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    diff += (vectun[i] - check[i]) * (vectun[i] - check[i]);
    diff2 += vectun[i] * vectun[i] - 2 * vectun[i] * check[i] + check[i] * check[i];
}
cout << scientific << endl << "\t\t\t\tНевязка сферическая" << endl << setw(14) << diff << ' ' << setw(14) << diff2 << endl;
//os << scientific << endl << "\t\t\t\tНевязка сферическая" << endl << setw(14) << diff << ' ' << setw(14) << diff2 << endl;
}

tdouble octahedron(tdouble *vectun)
{
tdouble diffo_2 = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    diffo_2 += abs(vectun[i]);
 //cout << scientific << endl << "\t\t\t\tНевязка октаэдрическая" << endl << setw(14) << diff << endl;
return diffo_2;
 // os << scientific << endl << "\t\t\t\tНевязка октаэдрическая" << endl << setw(14) << diff << endl;
}


tdouble octahedron(tdouble *vectun, tdouble *check)
{
  tdouble diffo_1 = 0.0;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    diffo_1 += abs(vectun[i] - check[i]);
//cout << scientific << endl << "\t\t\t\tНевязка октаэдрическая" << endl << setw(14) << diff << endl;
return diffo_1; 
//  os << scientific << endl << "\t\t\t\tНевязка октаэдрическая" << endl << setw(14) << diff << endl;
 }

 tdouble cubic(tdouble *vectun, tdouble *check)
 {
tdouble diffc_1 = abs(vectun[0] - check[0]); //максимум модуля ищется => запоминаем самую первую разность, а затем с ней сравниваем
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    if (diffc_1 < abs(vectun[i] - check[i]))
        diffc_1 = abs(vectun[i] - check[i]);
}
// cout << scientific << endl << "\t\t\t\tНевязка кубическая" << endl << setw(14) << diff << endl;
return diffc_1;
//os << scientific << endl << "\t\t\t\tНевязка кубическая" << endl << setw(14) << diff << endl;
}

tdouble cubic(tdouble *vectun)
{
tdouble diffc_2 = abs(vectun[0]); //максимум модуля ищется => запоминаем самую первую разность, а затем с ней сравниваем
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    if (diffc_2 < abs(vectun[i]))
        diffc_2 = abs(vectun[i]);
}
// cout << scientific << endl << "\t\t\t\tНевязка кубическая" << endl << setw(14) << diff << endl;
return diffc_2;
//os << scientific << endl << "\t\t\t\tНевязка кубическая" << endl << setw(14) << diff << endl;
}


tdouble cubic_matrix(tdouble **mtxun)
{
tdouble norm = 0;
tdouble maxn = norm;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        norm += abs(mtxun[i][j]);
    if (norm > maxn)
        maxn = norm; 
    norm = 0;
}
norm= maxn;
return norm;
}

tdouble octah_matrix(tdouble **mtxun)
{
tdouble norm = 0;
tdouble maxn = norm;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        norm += abs(mtxun[j][i]);
    if (norm > maxn)
        maxn = norm;
    norm = 0;
}
norm = maxn;
return norm;
}
```

Comment: Значит, где-то ловишь floating point underflow, или упираешься в машинный ноль для float (ЕМНИП там не так много, 1е-12 примерно).

Comment: Как это исправить? Матрица-то невырожденная и qr-алгоритму нули не страшны.

Answer (score 5):

Ну собственно что и следовало ожидать. Тип данных `float` занимает (обычно) 4 байта, а `double` — 8, есть ещё `long double`, он 10 байт. Соответственно чем больше места на тип, тем больше он хранит информации и тем точнее результат вычисления.

Если вы вычисляете *число обусловленности*, то понимаете, что это по сути показатель, насколько ошибки вычислений скажутся на конечный результат (чем больше число тем больше итоговая погрешность).

Поэтому пишите `double` (а лучше `long`). Если и после этого результат не устраивает, есть смысл почитать о компенсирующих вычислениях, повышении точности и прочее. Возможно вам поможет статья «[Всё, точка, приплыли! Учимся работать с числами с плавающей точкой и разрабатываем альтернативу с фиксированной точностью десятичной дроби](http://habrahabr.ru/company/xakep/blog/257897/)».

Comment: Мне по заданию требуется "float". Так бы я писал "long double" и не парился бы особо

Comment: Прочитай статью, если не помогло реализовывай длинную арифметику вообще на int - ах, а вообще полностью задание оговаривать тогда надо. Я думаю в методичке по предмету есть алгоритмы с повышенной устойчивостью.

Comment: В методичке просят вычислить с типом "double", а потом "float". Собственно, и всего. Я не очень понял, все равно, как эту проблему в моем случае решить

Comment: @MGMKLML возможно, специально просят вычислить с обоими типами, чтобы продемонстрировать потерю точности при использовании float. Дело в том, что когда Вы вычисляете сумму чисел, у которых большая разница в порядке, то накапливается ошибка округления. Например, если к 1e+10 прибавить 1e-10, то получим все равно 1e+10. Жаль, что Вы не привели полученную обратную матрицу - возможно, ее числа как раз сильно отличаются по порядку от чисел исходной.

Comment: @boeing777 Кстати, вроде было что-то такое, в смысле порядка.